# Tornado Web Request Origin

Tags: cors, tornado

After I've set up CORS headers for my tornado instance to allow cross-domain requests, I need to know if there's a way to get request's origin (i.e. to know which website tried to access my API via ajax) in tornado. I need this for certain logging and email reporting.
We have multiple separate front ends that reside on different domain names that use a single API to get resources and I need to know exactly which of those many tried to access our API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin is sent in the `Origin` HTTP header, i.e. `self.request.headers.get('Origin')`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Origin

Answer (score -2):

You can check this in `request` object. `RequestHandler.request.remote_ip` will give you IP address and `RequestHandler.request.host` will give you the host.

On Tornado documentation - [link](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.request)

sample code:

```
...
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        host_name = self.request.host
        host_ip = self.request.remote_ip
        # do something with host_name and host_ip, may be save it on database
...
```

Comment: "Origin" has a specific meaning in the context of CORS and is  unrelated to the client's IP.  It's similar to the Referer, but not quite the same.